# Can iTunes display the TV season image and the episode image in the correct way?

Tags: itunes, metadata, album-art

I'm trying to add artwork to my ripped TV shows in iTunes and coming across a bit of a problem getting the correct images to be displayed.

If I set each episode to have the correct ***episode image*** then the image displayed for the series is the same image as the first episode in the list. It's not quite so bad on iTunes, but on an iPad you don't get the show text and so the image alone is completely useless when you're trying to work out what the show is.

[image: Right episode image, wrong series image]

If I set each episode to have the correct ***series image*** then the image displayed for the TV show is correct but every single episode has the same series image. Which makes the whole picture on the right hand side rather redundant.

[image: Right series image, wrong episode image]

Is there any way to merge the two together, so (in the examples above) I get the season 2 image for the show and the correct episode image for each episode?

Comment: Where do you see individual episode images?  I don't see them in any lists or views.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure as I don't have iTunes to hand right now - but definitely an issue on an iPad or iPhone where you have a list of each episode with the associated TV show image.

Comment: How are you setting the series image? I hardly use iTunes for TV but I've never seen a distinct episode image on iTunes.  All episodes have the same series image.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best you can do (at least without hacking plists) is to just live with it.  Set the series image as the episode image for the first episode and use episode images for the rest.